# How to access a third dimension array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to access `tLastName` in this json file:

```
{
  "PlayerInfo": {
    "76561198090954934": {
      "uUserID": 1,
      "tFirstName": "[TAG] Flooze",
      "tLastName": "[TAG] Flooze",
      "iInitTimestamp": 1455213482,
      "iLastSeen": 1455667539,
      "tInitIP": "---",
      "tLastIP": "---",
      "iSecondsPlayed": 66990,
      "iConnections": 12,
      "tReason": "Disconnected",
      "bAlive": false
    },
    "76561198001294252": {
      "uUserID": 2,
      "tFirstName": "[HUN] Pepe",
      "tLastName": "[HUN] Pepe",
      "iInitTimestamp": 1455213482,
      "iLastSeen": 1455316439,
      "tInitIP": "---",
      "tLastIP": "---",
      "iSecondsPlayed": 28210,
      "iConnections": 2,
      "tReason": "Disconnected",
      "bAlive": true
    }
  }
}
```

it is a list with many of these and I would like it to echo just "tLastName" for each of them in php.

I have already got:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://nbd.esy.es/json/jsondb.json');
$json = json_decode($file, true);
```

So this should put it into an array?

Comment: foreach loop through $json perhaps

Comment: `foreach ($json['PlayerInfo'] as $player) echo $player['tLastName'] . "\n";`?

Comment: This is a technicality but I read on stackoverflow that php doesn't have "dimensions" for arrays. For example defining $arr [2][2]=5 doesn't necessarily make a $arr [1][2]

Comment: This is a technicality but I read on stackoverflow that php doesn't have "dimensions" for arrays. For example defining $arr [2][2]=5 doesn't necessarily make a $arr [1][2]. Rather it's more of a nested array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://nbd.esy.es/json/jsondb.json');
$json = json_decode($file, true);

foreach ($json['PlayerInfo'] as $playerInfo) {
    $lastName = $playerInfo['tLastName'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So first off all you json is incorrect. `"uUserID": ---` should be something like `"uUserID": "---"`with the quotes. But this maybe because you deleted the id's so we can not see them. If that is fixed this solution will work:

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://nbd.esy.es/json/jsondb.json');
$json = json_decode($file);

foreach ($json->PlayerInfo as $playerInfo) {
    $lastName = $playerInfo->tLastName;
    echo $lastName;
}
```

Your json is actually not an array but an Object with objects in there